# What is the likely penalty for an organisation failing to comply with a subject access request by many months, on the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd occasions?

Tags: england-and-wales, data-protection

ACME Inc. Receives a subject access request from Bob, and fails to respond to it for 5 months. What are the likely sanctions faced by ACME, in case this was the:

- 1st,
- 2nd,
- or 3rd

Such incident of not complying with the data protection legislation?

Comment: What has Bob been doing about it, if anything? If Bob has done nothing, then the likely penalty is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As a data protection professional, I have personally observed an organisation in the UK fail to comply fully with a subject access request for more than two years. It faced no formal enforcement action from the ICO, but the data subject did invoke their complaints procedure, and a case officer was trying to get some traction with the organisation.

The ICO is quicker to turn around complaints now, but appears softer on (UK GDPR) enforcement. When I personally had an issue with a tardy DSAR, I used the ICO's new complaints interface, which suggested I should wait a certain amount of additional time for the controller to respond, beyond the statutory deadline, before making a complaint.

That being said, technically they could be fined, publicly reprimanded, etc. for their noncompliance. And the data subject will still have the right to (a) request [compensation](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2016/679/article/82) in case the noncompliance causes them *damage*; and/or (b) a [judicial remedy](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2016/679/article/79) where they believe their rights have been infringed.